# Can figure out why jQuery script is not talking to ASP.NET web API properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a 500 error when I try to run this script. I have a demo project set up in asp.net mvc4 with a small web api controller, and the default home controller. here is my api controller:

```
namespace MyTrainingApi.Controllers
{

public class CoursesController : ApiController
{

    //for demo mock data, would pull from dbContext here. 
    static List<Course> _courses = InitCourses();

    private static List<Course> InitCourses()
    {
        var ret = new List<Course>();
        ret.Add(new Course { id = 0, name = "HTTP Fundamentals" });
        ret.Add(new Course { id = 1, name = "HTTP Fundamentals Part 2" });
        ret.Add(new Course { id = 2, name = "HTTP Fundamentals Part 3" });
        ret.Add(new Course { id = 3, name = "How to bake a cake" });

        return ret;
    }

    //uri: /api/courses/
    public IEnumerable<Course> Get()
    {
        return _courses;
    }

    //uri: /api/courses/{id}
    public Course Get(int id)
    {
        Course ret = null;
        ret = (from c in _courses where c.id == id select c).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ret == null)
        {
            //TODO: return 404
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Course Post(Course newCourse)
    {
        newCourse.id = _courses.Count();
        _courses.Add(newCourse);
        //TODO: return 202
        return newCourse;
    }

}

public class Course
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my HomeController:

```
namespace MyTrainingApi.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Course(int id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

So I have three views that i am experimenting with: Index is a list of all courses, Course is one course based off of id, and Create which is supposed to POST back some info and add a Course. The Create view is the one I am having issues with here. This is the view code:

[image]

The error message says this:

No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Course' from content with media type ''undefined''.

Comment: You are missing the data option with your ajax request and may be that could be creating an issue

Comment: Yep, you are doing a POST, but not including any data to post, and your API is expecting a Course

Comment: ya I am new to all this. Studying relentlessly, but I still have a hard time with all this

Comment: Ok so I can see why I want to specify data, but how do I say the data is an Object Course?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out, thanks to the tip about specifying the data in the comments I added this like to the ajax request

data: { id: 0, name:  $('#name').val()  }

And now it works!